# .jar que no se ejecuta

Tags: java, netbeans

Cree un proyecto en **NetBeans** con Java JDK 8u131 y JRE 8u131, en el proyecto utilizo una biblioteca llamada **JXL** que, como saben, se utiliza para exportar e importar tablas Excel.

El proyecto funciona muy bien cuando lo ejecuto en el mismo NetBeans, la cosa es cuando genero el **.jar** este no se abre, imagino que por la biblioteca que estoy usando.

Por ejemplo, en otros proyecto he usado otras bibliotecas como *jCalendar* o *Jtatoo* y este problema no me lo genera.

¿Alguien sabe por qué pasa ese error?

Comment: Aunque faltan detalles de que error esta saliendo, lo mas seguro es que la falla sea por classpath, los Ide normalmente ejecutan haciendo una inclusion de classpath completa, lo cual no equivale a la que uno hace en consola

Comment: Al generar el .jar netBeans Muestra esto:Note: D:\Universidad\ProyectoEtecsa\src\Clases\Export_Excel.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\Universidad\ProyectoEtecsa\src\proyectoetecsa\Visual.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. Aunque al final pone BuilSucsesfull

Comment: Y al ejecutarlo que sucede? que muestra?

Comment: Nada, no se ejecuta

Comment: y como estas ejecutando tu jar?

Comment: Con el build el jar se guarda en la carpeta dist donde esta el proyecto y eso es lo que se de be ejecutar al dar clic, se me pone en el administrador de tareas pero no se abre la consola que es lo esperado. En otros proyectos no da este problema asi que de softwere no debe ser

Comment: Intenta desde cmd o consola java -jar nombredetujar.jar y peganos el stacktrace

Comment: Como puedo Hacerlo?

Comment: Ok ya lo puse y hace exactamente lo mismo, o sea nada, igual que si le doy clic me lo pone en el adm de tareas como javaw.exe en proceso pero como dije antes no lo ejecuta como tal

Comment: puedes poner tu código parece que no es que no haga nada, sino que tu no imprimes nada en pantalla (System.out) en el main y hay un hilo corriendo

Comment: No creo sea ese el problema pues en el netbeans si me ejecuta todo perfecto, es el jar que no abre

Comment: segun pude investigar aunque no entendi muy bien dicen que debe ser porque la biblioteca jxl es obsoleta, que puedo hacer ahora

Comment: intenta abrir tu cmd desde la carpeta bin donde tengas instalado java y ejecuta el comando jps y revisa si se alcanza a inicializar algun proceso relacionado con lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Hermano, nada ya vi donde estaba el problema, despues de revisar minusiosamente el codigo, al proyecto le habia puesto un icono en la barra principal con minuscula y el fichero era en mayusculas. Cosas como estas me dan ganas de explotar. Muchas gracias igual y disculpa todas las molestias ocacionas por mi idiotes. Gracias y aqui estamos

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el archivo MANIFEST que se encuentra dentro de tu jar generado? Puedes abrir tu jar con winzip, winrar o simplemente cambiando la extensión a zip

Answer (score 1):

Considera que cuando exportas tu jar solo contiene **tus clases**, no se exportan sus dependencias. Esto independiente del IDE, es decir que sucedería exactamente lo mismo con Eclipse e IntelliJ también. Y es lo correcto, porque tu proyecto solo contiene esas clases y recursos que has indicado en él.

Lo que se hace en estos casos es agregar las librerías de las que depende tu proyecto en una carpeta `lib` e indicar que los jar que se encuentran allí pertenecen al classpath (ruta donde encontrar más clases) durante la ejecución del proyecto.

Asumiendo que tu jar se llama `miproyecto.jar` y tienes la siguiente estructura de carpetas:

```
- usr
. - ernestoperez
  . + miproyecto.jar
  . - lib
    . + jxl.jar
```

Entonces al ubicarte con la línea de comandos en la carpeta `ernestoperez` podrías ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
java -cp "lib/*" -jar miproyecto.jar
```

Más información (en inglés):

- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/including-all-the-jars-in-a-directory-within-the-java-classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/219801/1065197)

Answer (score 0):

En **Netbeans** en las propiedades, debes indicar en que clase está el método MAIN que iniciará la ejecución de todo.

En el proyecto también debes tener relacionado que librerías usa (archivos .JAR)

Luego, le das "**Clean and Build**" al proyecto y buscas en la carpeta DIST en el explorador de archivos (donde está tu proyecto) el archivo .JAR empaquetado.

Si te vas desde CMD, la consola de comandos hasta la carpeta DIST, allí puedes hacer:

```
java -jar (nombre de tu proyecto).jar
```

Y debería ejecutarse correctamente.

Netbeans debería poner tus librerías en una carpeta, al mismo nivel del JAR creado.

Si te llevas la aplicación creada a otra carpeta u otro equipo, recuerda llevar también, además del proyecto.jar la carpeta lib que siempre debe estar al mismo nivel.