# .jar no ejecuta fuera de Apache Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, maven, javamail, netbeans-11.3

Tengo un proyecto Java (App) que he creado en Apache Netbeans, el cual tiene una dependencia con `javax.mail 1.6.2`(está agregada en el archivo `pom.xml` de la siguiente forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>App</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>App.Principal</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

); cuando trato de ejecutar el .jar creado, me aparece el error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
        at App.Pantalla.<init>(Pantalla.java:28)
        at App.Principal.main(Principal.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more`.

Según estuve leyendo en [Jar que no se ejecuta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/88595/jar-que-no-se-ejecuta), debería importar el jar de la dependencia a mi proyecto; pero para esta nueva versión, no veo que esté disponible esta opción.

Actualmente estaba probando con `java -Xmx1024m -jar C:\Users\...\NetBeansProjects\App\target\App-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` y con `java -cp C:\Users\...\.m2\repository\com\sun\mail\javax.mail\1.6.2\javax.mail-1.6.2.jar -Xmx1024m -jar App-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`; pero ninguna me ha resultado por ahora. ¿Qué otras opciones me quedan para poder ejecutar el .jar de mi proyecto fuera del entorno de Netbeans?

Ya al menos modifiqué el archivo `pom.xml` para que detectara la clase principal de mi proyecto.

---

Actualización:

Mi archivo MANIFES.MF ahora se ve así:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: angel
Class-Path: lib/activation-1.1.jar lib/javax.mail-1.6.2.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_241
Main-Class: App.Principal
```

luego de modificar mi `pom.xml`

Comment: Con el segundo comando que resultado tienes? Podrías compartir la parte del POM donde defines la clase que contiene el `main()`?

Comment: @E.Betanzos he agregado ambos en la pregunta, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que te está faltando la configuración del classpath en el jar.
Tendrias que modificar el pom de esta forma:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.mycompany.App.Principal</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Nota: Cuando usas java -jar xxx.jar, el parámetro -cp se ignora y el class path se toma toma del Manifest del jar.

Luego en la carpeta que pongas el `jar`, tenes que crear la carpeta `lib` e incluir ahi los `jar` de las dependencias. En este caso el `jar` de `com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.2`.

Preguntas relacionadas:
[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError con CLASSPATH explícito](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/350293/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-con-classpath-expl%C3%ADcito)
[¿Cómo funciona CLASSPATH?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/350588/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-classpath)

Comment: Muchas gracias, Juan. Agregué la sección que indicas en el archivo pom.xml 
y, en la ruta C:\...\NetBeansProjects\BTC\target que es donde se genera el jar, existe la carpeta libs con los 2 archivos.jar que tengo declarados como repositorios (dado que me faltaba declarar el otro en pom.xml, también lo agregué); pero aun me arroja el mismo error cuando lo ejecuto como dices

Comment: tenes que correr el java -jar xxx.jar estando en la carpeta target, osea donde esta el jar ejecutable y la carpeta lib con los jars dependientes adento.

Comment: Y una cosa mas que me di cuenta recién. El main class tiene que estar con el full qualified name. com.micompania.App.Principal. Suponiendo que com.micompania.App es el package y Principal el nombre de clase que tienen el main.

Comment: @Juan como lo tiene definido está correcto, fíjate que la traza dice que el problema está en esa clase: `at App.Principal.main(Principal.java:23)`. El problema es que mo configuración apuntaba a `libs` y la tuya a `lib`.

Comment: Juan, com.micompania era el "Group ID" que me creó por defecto Netbeans, y sí, así lo estaba ejecutando. Muchas gracias nuevamente por el apoyo y la documentación enlaza a la pregunta, la revisaré para poder actualizar mi conocimiento

Answer (score 2):

Completando la respuesta de @Juan puedes configurar el `maven-dependency-plugin` para copiar las dependencias de tu proyecto a la carpeta `lib`. De otro modo tendrías que copiar manualmente los jars.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/lib
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

**Edición**

El `outputDirectory` debe apuntar a `lib` en vez de a `libs`, para ser consecuente con la respuesta de @Juan.

```
${project.build.directory}/lib
```

Comment: Muchas gracias E. Betanzos, esta sección del código me ayudó para ver que tenía que agregar otra dependencia a mi pom.xml y lo hice, pero aun no funciona

Comment: Fallo mio, te acabo de editar la respuesta

Comment: Claro, me fijé más en encajar la respuesta de ambos que en la ruta de la librería. Muchas gracias por la rapidez y explicación en tu respuesta. Estoy un poco oxidado en Java y trato de recuperar el tiempo.