# construir correctamente un JAR en netbeans: no main manifest attribute

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, java-17

Desde hace una semana he estado investigando sobre cómo crear un jar para mí aplicación, pero no he encontrado nada que me ayude y la verdad estoy un poco frustrado, así vengo a pedir su ayuda.
Cree mi archivo .jar compilado el código con NetBeans que se guarda en una carpeta llamada 'target'.
Aclaraciones: Estoy usando NetBeans 17, el JDK 17, para mi proyecto tengo 3 paquetes que creé, más aparte el paquete donde se encuentra la clase principal.

1. Cuando intento ejecutar mi archivo compilado .jar me sale: "no main manifest attribute, in Calculadora_v01-0.jar", buscando el error encontré que necesito un archivo Manifest.txt
2. Creé el archivo Manifest.txt y ejecutando: "...\calculadora\target>jar cmf Manifest.txt Calculadora_v01-0.jar *.class" me sale el error: "*.class : no such file or directory"

Comment: el tipo de proyecto me parece que es [maven] debido a la carpeta `target`, aunque esta carpeta también esta presente en los proyectos de [gradle]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [.jar no ejecuta fuera de Apache Netbeans](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/358670/jar-no-ejecuta-fuera-de-apache-netbeans)

Comment: no, ya que no me sale nignuna excepcion.

Answer (score 0):

El archivo manifest.txt, debe contener la línea:

> Main-Class: **ClaseMain**

Después debes crear nuevamente el jar, con el comando:

> jar cfm Calculadora_v01-0.jar Manifest.txt **ClaseMain**.class

Solo para aclarar, debes sustituir **ClaseMain** por el nombre del archivo que contiene el método main().

Comment: eso ya lo hice, pero me sale el error que puse en mi punto 2, y no sé que puede estar pasando.